# Dart - How to format DateTime based on device timezone?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am a newbie to Dart.
I am currently facing a problem to format my DateTime to display the time based on the device's timezone.
Can someone advise me how can I achieve that?
My current code as following:

```
DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy hh:mm')
```

Output Sample:
11 Mar 2019 07:04

Expectation:
My device is using GMT+8 at the moment, I am expecting it to display as 11 Mar 2019 15.04.

Please advise.
Thanks!!

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl should help you with that

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Install the [intl package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl) and then use the DateFormat.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

```
final dateFormatter = DateFormat('d MMMM yyyy hh:mm');
print(dateFormatter.format(your_date_time_object));
```

Comment: @user3180690 awesome. mark as correct so other members can know what it worked .

Comment: I think it should use DateFormat instead of DateForm

Answer (score 26):

For converting UTC to Local Timezone :

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

var dateValue = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ").parseUTC("2020-06-14T18:55:21Z").toLocal();
String formattedDate = DateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm").format(dateValue);
debugPrint("formattedDate = "+formattedDate);
```

Comment: Oh, finally. Thank you, I've been struggling converting a simple UTC date in local timezone for about 2 hours, it's ridiculous, lol.

Answer (score 5):

To make sure your DateTime uses the device's current timezone always use toLocal().

DateTime.toLocal() documentation:
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.5/dart-core/DateTime/toLocal.html

So simply do:

```
DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy hh:mm').format(myDate.toLocal())
```

Answer (score 3):

I fetched data from laravel api

laravel dateTimeUTC like 2021-05-21T17:33:24.000000Z

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


String dateTime = "2021-05-21T17:33:24.000000Z" // String datetime UTC zone

DateTime parsedDateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ").parseUTC(dateTime).toLocal(); // parse String datetime to DateTime and get local date time 

String formatedDateTime = DateFormat.yMd().add_jm().format(parsedDateFormat).toString(); // convert local date time to string format local date time

// output is 5/21/2021 11:03PM
```