# error when trying to change DateTime to string that has time zone format in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-intl

so I use intl package. here is my code

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

String toString(DateTime originalDate) {
    initializeDateFormatting();
    final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat("EEEE, d MMMM. HH:mm zzz", "id");
    final String formatted = formatter.format(originalDate);
    return formatted;
  }
```

as you can see, I am trying to make DateTime as a string using `"EEEE, d MMMM. HH:mm zzz"` format. so I expect I will have the result date string like this:

> Senin, 24 Mei. 18:00 WIB.

but I have error whenever I have that `zzz` in the format. if I remove the `zzz` then it should be fine.

I guess I need to put a TimeZone ID in my code above. because I has this unimplemented error in `date_format_field.dart` file

```
String formatTimeZone(DateTime date) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
```

but I don't know how to set the timezoneID to my code. my TimeZone ID is "Asia/Jakarta"

I am okay if you have different code or not using intl package at all. as long as I can specify the timezone and the locale ID

Comment: [`package:intl` has not implemented time zone formatting](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/74) (nor parsing).  You instead probably should use [`package:timezone`](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) instead.

Answer (score 0):

duplicate of
[Dart - How to format DateTime based on device timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55097746/dart-how-to-format-datetime-based-on-device-timezone)

try using this:

```
String toString(DateTime originalDate) {
    initializeDateFormatting();
    final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat("EEEE, d MMMM. HH:mm zzz").parseUTC(dateTime).toLocal();
    final String formatted = formatter.format(originalDate);
    return formatted;
  }
```